# Find object in state by id, if object found do something, if object not found do something else

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ecmascript-6, vuex

I need to check first if an object with the payload ID exists in my shippingFees array (vuex state), if the object exists I need to replace it with the payload, else I just need to push the payload to the shippingFees array.

Right now I'm looping over each object in shippingFees, but it doesn't check if the object exists first and will just push the object to the array if the ID doesn't match.. How can I check if an object with the ID exists in the array first and do something, and then if it doesn't exist do something else? :)

```
SET_SHIPPING_FEES: (state, payload) => {
  if (state.shippingFees.length > 0) {
    for (let i = 0; i < state.shippingFees.length; i += 1) {
      if (state.shippingFees[i].id === payload.id) {
        state.shippingFees.splice(i, 1);
        state.shippingFees.push(payload);
      } else {
        state.shippingFees.push(payload);
      }
    }
  } else {
    state.shippingFees.push(payload);
  }
}
```

Comment: [Array.prototype.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) or [Array.prototype.findIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex)

Comment: Do you have an example @RoyJ? :)

Comment: Really, it looks like you just want to use `payload` as the 3rd argument to `splice`, and get rid of the `push` in that branch of the `if`.

Comment: Have you tried using `Array.prototype.some()`?

Comment: Did you work it out?

Comment: Please don't include answers in the question text.  If you found the answer to your own question and think it would be helpful to future users you [can add it as a regular answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SOLVED

I used the .some() method to solve the problem.

Here's the code I used:

```
SET_SHIPPING_FEES: (state, payload) => {
   if (state.shippingFees.length > 0) {
     const shippingFeeDoesExist = state.shippingFees.some(fee => fee.id === 
     payload.id);

     if (shippingFeeDoesExist) {
      for (let i = 0; i < state.shippingFees.length; i += 1) {
        if (state.shippingFees[i].id === payload.id) {
          state.shippingFees.splice(i, 1, payload);
        }
      }
    } else {
      state.shippingFees.push(payload);
    }
  } else {
    state.shippingFees.push(payload);
  }
},
```